# Nginx Default/Welcome Page Suddenly Returns

Tags: nginx, security

I installed Nginx a number of months ago and deployed some code. I obviously deleted the default index.html Nginx default page. I know this for certain as PHP was not installed and so index.html was the homepage.

Everything was working fine until I got an email from someone telling me that they couldn't access site. The Nginx Default/Welcome page was being displayed! I immediately investigated and the correct index.html file was overridden.

My immediate reaction was that it was a security incident but I have been through all the server logs and can find no unauthorised access. I am also confident that I did not accidentally upload the file - I have searched my computer and I don't even have a copy of the welcome page.

Has anyone ever seen this happen before or know how this could possibly happen? I have absolutely no idea what caused it and so cannot put the processes in place to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: My money is on an automatic update of nginx.  This is one of the bajillion reasons you should never use automatic updates in a production environment.

Comment: @yoonix Thank you for your response. Could an update cause the welcome page to be redisplayed? If so, I'm guessing this must affect a lot of people?

Comment: Yes it could, depending on how the package was built.  The package installed index.html it in the first place.  A newer version of the package (aka update) would likely do the same if the file was missing.

Comment: @yoonix: The problem isn't *automatic* updates, per se; even if the OP installed the updated packages "by hand", the welcome page still would have been invisibly nuked and the OP wouldn't have known until the report came in that the site was down.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your distribution and how nginx was installed it's impossible to know for sure, but it's highly likely the problem is that the nginx package was upgraded, and overwrote the `index.html` you created.  This happens because files outside of `/etc` in most Linux distributions are considered "managed by the package manager", and so local modifications to those files will be overwritten by package updates.

The solution is to not use the default location that nginx uses, but to instead configure nginx to look somewhere else on the system, and put your website content there.  Then, the package can do whatever it wants to the default welcome page, and you never need care.